# Check if service is running without using Find command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In a batch file I'm trying to check if a service is started, if not then wait.

Now to check if a service is running, I am doing this:

```
sc query "serviceName" | find /i "RUNNING"
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    echo serviceName is running.
) else (
    echo serviceName is not running
)
```

Trouble is the errorlevel is always set to 0. Possibly because of this known [Find bug](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/106203).
Is there any alternate way to check if a service is started, if not then wait?

Comment: Avoid to "reset" the %errorlevel% variable in your code. If you set it to any value, commands will set correctly the errorlevel value BUT NOT the %errorlevel% variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code will work fine, if you aren't using `Windows NT version 3.1 and Windows NT Advanced Server version 3.1` and your service name doesn't include `running`.

Perhaps it is within a loop and so you should use this (or delayed expansion):

```
sc query "serviceName" | find /i "RUNNING"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo serviceName is running.
) else (
    echo serviceName is not running
)
```

Comment: aah.Brackets block.Didn't come to me.+1

Answer (score 10):

You could use `Findstr` instead of `Find` command:

```
sc query "Service name" | findstr /i "RUNNING" 1>nul 2>&1 && (
    echo serviceName is running.
) || (
    echo serviceName is not running
)
```

You can do it also using `wmic` command:

```
wmic service where name="Service name" get State | Findstr /I "Running" 1>NUL 2>&1 && (
    echo serviceName is running.
) || (
    echo serviceName is not running
)
```

Another thing to notice for the future is that when comparing numeric values you should not enclose expressions with quotes `""`, so the condition should look like this:

```
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 () ELSE ()
```

Answer (score 4):

Works for me.Is it possible your ERRORLEVEL variable to be overwriten or your code to be in brackets block?
try one of these:

```
sc query "serviceName" | findstr /i "RUNNING"
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo serviceName is running.
) else (
    echo serviceName is not running
)
```

or

```
sc query "serviceName" | findstr /i "RUNNING" && (
    echo serviceName is running.
    goto :skip_not_w
) 
echo serviceName is not running
:skip_not_w
```

The cited bug is for `windows nt` (is this your OS?) and should be fixed already...If your os is NT , you should parse the output of the command with `FOR /F` to see it contains `RUNNING` or use `FINDSTR`

Answer (score 3):

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "serviceName" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   echo Service not started
   net start "serviceName"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with a function:

```
:IsServiceRunning servicename
sc query "%~1"|findstr "STATE.*:.*4.*RUNNING">NUL

Usage Example:

Call :IsServiceRunning service && Service is running || Service isn't running
```